# How to snapshot a file in meantime modify it?

Tags: java, hdfs

Now I try to conquer a problem. The problem is that I have a file which may update in random time, clients will download it, when clients download log file, I need to snapshot that file. However, The file may update when downing. How to make sure the copy of log file is the same as user downed one?

Comment: What you need to do is keep ALL the copies of you files and list of all the clients who downloaded that version. You can then have a scheduled task that will delete all the copies that have not been downloaded by anyone one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the download process.

When they click download, you should first copy the file (your snapshot).

Then send them the copy of the file, not the active one.